# How to extract value by key in MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, json

I have a json and i want to extract the value by a key. Not sure how I can implement it. Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
set @JSON = 
'[
{
    "key": "address",
    "value": "xxx"
},
{
    "key": "addr_lng",
    "value": 100.22
},
{
    "key": "addr_lat",
    "value": 300.22
}
]';
```

I want to extract the value by key `addr_lat`, but don't want change the json structure.

```
300.22
```

Comment: Consider [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=31dd97ec908b084f7f1f7178627865e0)

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"address": xxx, "addr_lng": 100.22, "addr_lat": 300.22}', '$.addr_lng') AS 'result';
```

https://database.guide/json_extract-return-data-from-a-json-document-in-mysql/

Comment: That's not an array of objects, it's a single object.